BULLX/PHANTOM HELP: PROGRAM ID ERROR / CAN'T SELL, BUY, OR WITHDRAW
A friend sent me $JollyWhale earlier today on phantom. I sent that to my bullx wallet. Now I can't buy or sell that coin.  My wallet isn't locked or anything. I get "Unkown error" everytime and a failed order.
_
I CHECKED SOL SCAN AND THIS IS THE ERROR I'M SEEING:
#1 Compute Budget instruction

Program returned success
#2 Compute Budget instruction
Program returned success
#3 Associated Token Account Program instruction
Program logged: "Create"
Program invoked: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Program logged: "Instruction: GetAccountDataSize"
Program logged: "Error: IncorrectProgramId"
Program consumed: 884 of 192606 compute units
Program returned error: "incorrect program id for instruction"
Program consumed: 7978 of 199700 compute units
Program returned error: "incorrect program id for instruction"

